# How to force an opencv image (cv::Mat) to release its memory

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   cv::Mat image;
public:
   init()
   {
        image=imread("test.jpg");
   }
   cv::Mat getImage()
   {
        return image;
    }
   void reset()
   {
      // what should I write here?
    }
}
cv::Mat myImage;

void main()
{
    MyClass myclass;
    myclass.init();
    myImage=myclass.getImage();
    // do something with image;
    myclass.reset();
    // at this point the memory allocated by myclass.image should be released and also myImage should be invalidated (be an empty image).
}
```

Note: I know that I can make the myImage a local variable and fix the problem, but I want to know how I can release the memory allocated by a cv::Mat even when the reference count is not zero.

image.release() don't release the memory as there is a copy of image (myImage) and I need to make sure that the memory is released even when there is a copy of image.

For people that may complain that it is not a good idea to invalidate the myImage, the class specification says that when reset is called, all images, which was created by class became invalid and if user need the image, they need to clone it before calling reset on the class.

## edit1

deallocate doesn't work and it doesn't release memory.

Comment: You will have to keep references to all places where the image is still used and reset those. Why do you bother? Why do you forcefully want to invalidate something?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt to release memory! I need the memory and I can not force my class user to release the memory. But if I release the memory, it will invalidate the copy of images.

Comment: Have you considered an approach similar to `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`?

Comment: Your class specification what it is, why don't you just store a raw pointer, e.g., `cv::Mat * MyClass::getImage()`. As good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

what about this code?

1. allocate memory to hold your image
2. create Mat header using that pre-allocated memory
3. copy loaded image to that memory

This should deactivate the reference counting.

I didn't try it, but I guess it should work (I hope the idea is clear). However, you'll obviously get access errors if there are other Mat references  which are still in use!

```
class MyClass
{
   cv::Mat image;
   unsigned char * imageData; // TODO: set to zero in constructor!
public:
   init()
   {
        cv::Mat tmp = imread("test.jpg");
        // TODO: test if non-zero and release before allocating new memory
        imageData = (unsigned char*) malloc(tmp.cols*tmp.rows*3*sizeof(unsigned char)); // allocate memory for your image
        // TODO: maybe it is possible to get the size of "tmp"'s data directly, which would be much better because of widthStep things, etc. The formula "tmp.cols*tmp.rows*3*sizeof(unsigned char)" might not be correct for all kind of input images!

        // create Mat header that uses present memory
        image=cv::Mat(tmp.rows, tmp.cols, 3, imageData  );

        // copy loaded image to allocated memory:
        tmp.copyTo(image); // here you must be sure that "image" is big enough to hold "tmp"'s data. Otherwise a new Mat will be created.

        // tmp will be cleared automatically
   }
   cv::Mat getImage()
   {
        return image;
   }
   void reset()
   {
      image = cv::Mat();
      free(imageData);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would do the job, but I have several images and managing all of them in this way is very cumbersome. Is there any better way to do this? Is there any way to force cv::Mat to release its memory?

Comment: not as far as I know, because that would destroy the intention of reference counting (but I didn't test it). Just pass a path to the initialize function, or pass a cv::Mat to the initialize function instead of hard-coding the path in the initialize function. Or do I not understand the problem? Maybe you could experiment with using cv::Mat pointers and/or calling the ::release function multiple times or something... AND you can always modify the openCV sourcecode to add some "killswitch" in the Mat object directly.

Comment: what about if I return a reference to image? does a reference a copy of image and it adds reference counter?

Comment: you should try that. But mind that the user can inrease the reference counter himself by passing that Mat reference to different variables or functions. Same if you return a pointer and the user de-references that pointer.

Comment: what you can do is to create a Mat in your class, but return a new Mat with reference to the Mat data. That's basically the same as in my code, but without malloc and free. In getImage you just return `cv::Mat(image.rows, image.cols, image.channels(), image.type(), image.widthstep(), image.data())`

Comment: give it a try! I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the real question is if this design makes sense. The only reason for the user of the class to keep the copy of the previously received `Mat` object when they call `reset` is if they still want to work on it. There is no other reason to keep that object. Consequently, invalidating this copy when calling `reset` is bound to result in a crash. Therefore that behaviour makes no sense. Furthermore it introduces an implicit constraint that the user must know about and that is not communicated through the interface of the class. This is no good design.

Instead, the responsibility for the memory usage is at the side of the class user. They know that if they call `getImage` and `reset` a hundred times while keeping all the images, they will consume a lot of memory. And it's their decision, not that of your class.

Instead, you should rather make sure you handle the case when memory is insufficient when creating new `Mat` object inside your class, so in case no new image can be created this is properly handled and communicated. After all you never know if there is enough memory for your image, even if you release the old image every time.

Answer (score -1):

getImage has to return a reference Mat& and image.release() in the reset function will do the job.